# Alter table does not add the foreign key restraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I've exported a database from Access to a MySQL server (local)

While doing this it did not export the foreign keys I had assigned in the database with them. While inconvenient I thought it didn't matter since I could add them manually. However when I use the following command:

```
alter table betalingsstatus 
add foreign key (bedrijf_id) 
references bedrijven(bedrijf_id)
```

It says it successfully did add the constraint. However when I insert something into the table and I add a number that isn't in the table bedrijven it still inserts it. I had the same problem with other foreign keys I have in the database.

Comment: What engine are you using? MyISAM doesn't enforce foreign keys.

Comment: found the solution with:
http://www.easyfrom.net/

Answer (score 0):

Put ENGINE=INNODB; after the creation - altering of those tables that you want to enforce the foreign key constraints.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl
(
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```